# How can I change the wiggle time of 'urgent animation' in Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

I really like wiggle animation for application notification, but I find it disappear too quickly and I wish I could change this delay. I looked through all the ccsm, appearance, and myUnity settings and nothing seems appropriate.

Comment: Nice question! Wiggle thing is too fast to really draw the user's attention

Comment: You can also go vote for these bugs: [Unity's sidebar Urgent icon animation not constant](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/776745) and [Launcher icon alert animation should repeat...](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/893196).  (Click on the pencil and say "Yes, it affects me".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a configurable option in Unity, but you can edit the source code to change the duration.  If you've not downloaded source and compiled your own packages before, you can do so as follows.  From your home directory in a terminal window:

```
mkdir src
cd src
apt-get source unity
cd unity-<version number>
gedit ./plugins/unityshell/src/Launcher.cpp
```

Look for the line which says:

```
Launcher.cpp:const int Launcher::Launcher::ANIM_DURATION_SHORT = 125;
```

and maybe double the duration.  If you've never built a package from source before you're going to need a few tools.  So do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
```

Then to get the dependencies neccessary for unity to build properly:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep unity
```

Finally create the package and install:

```
debuild -us -uc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i unity*.deb
```

If you're having problems with dependencies let me know, and I'll try to help you figure out what you're missing.

Comment: Never got notify of the answer here. First of all, Launcher.cpp is now in unity-.../launcher/ folder, but I found it and updated the variable there. Then on the last step I was missing some dependencies and I was able to resolve them with apt-get -f install. Eventually I got stuck on     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity:
 unity depends on libunity-core-6.0-5 (= 7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of libunity-core-6.0-5 on system is 7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1systray1.

Comment: This Patch is only increasing the animation duration and not the wiggle time. To be clear: With an higher integer in ANIM_DURATION_SHORT, the wiggle animation gets slower. So it does only wiggle 2 times before it fades after a second where it did 6 wiggles before in one second. (time and quantity of wiggles is exemplary. I did not measure time and number of wiggles exactly.)