# I've lost my Wiggle ! Unity launcher animations stopped working. 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

The *Launch* and *Urgent* animations for the launcher icons in my Unity sidebar have stopped working - I have restored the defaults. I have Unity tweak and Compiz Unity plugin (both in sync with each other).

I thought I could handle missing a tiny thing like this, but not knowing if an application is still loading or I've just not clicked the icon properly is incredibly annoying.

If it makes an difference, I did install Ubuntu server first and then Ubuntu Desktop on top of it.

I have an ATI graphics card and it's working fine with the community drivers, 2d and 3d acceleration, and I have compiz with some silly interface things (wobbly windows - love that one) turned on.

Comment: What do you mean by stopped working? What does it do when you start application? can you grab a screenshot?

Comment: set an urgent flag on a LaucherEntry and it will wiggle.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124384/how-to-let-an-icon-in-the-launcher-wiggle  http://askubuntu.com/questions/136890/how-do-i-customize-the-launcher-animations

Comment: @Anwar it does nothing, I click it, I wait, the application opens but no animation on launcher icon. A screen grab is pointless here - it would be of an icon not animating.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the links. The second one is what I am doing anyway - this isn't a 'how to' question, but the first one is more like it - it might not be the same for 16.04  (thatanswer was for 12.04) but knowing where the API documentation is a great help, thanks.

Comment: @Rinzwind 'r.e set an urgent flag' This flag should be 'set' when an application triggers it, it isn't something I am interested in setting myself.