# How do I customize the launcher animations?

Tags: unity, launcher

When I get Skype messages I tend not to notice the launcher animation. The highlighted icon is then not enough to catch my attention once the animation is done.

Although I agree with the default here, is there a way I can make the animation continuous until I click it?

Comment: Related - http://askubuntu.com/questions/121471/how-can-i-change-the-wiggle-time-of-urgent-animation-in-unity-launcher >.>

Comment: I've a similar issue. Whenever I open a file with the _explorer_ (don't know the right term in ubuntu) window opened but not in front, the icon just shakes; and I keep waiting for the folder to open (Windows style). An intuitive thing is that the explorer should be brought to top automatically

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you cannot make the animation constant in the current version of Unity.

Maybe if you change the animation "Pulse" it may be more obvious. You can also set it to "None" if you want to totally turn off the animation. To do this:

- Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] (see also: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) )
- Open the Unity plugin's settings by:

  - Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
  - Typing `about:config`
  - Pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>
- You will be presented with this Window:
  [image]
- Select the Experimental tab, and from there, choose Pulse as the "Urgent Animation":
  [image]