# How do I stop unity launcher icon from shaking wobbling, jumping, bouncing, running, and cavorting?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I customize the launcher animations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136890/how-do-i-customize-the-launcher-animations)

When I'm focused and working on something, sometimes an app (like update manager) will decide that it is more important than I am, and start jumping and bouncing and wobbling and waving and generally cavorting around like a spoiled, misbehaving 3-year-old. In general, being very annoying.

How do I stop this behavior?

I'll get to an app when I get to it - it shouldn't be so needy.
I need to work, not spend all day at the service of whatever application pops up.

Comment: Actually, it's the exact opposite request..

Comment: @ssu - really?  Follow the linked guide - doesn't setting the animation to none do what you have asked?

Comment: Yes, it really is the exact opposite request ;) The link asks how to make the animation last longer. I want to turn it off. Setting it to none (the opposite of what the link recommends) seems to be OK so far.

Comment: I downvoted the question because it has extraneous material (shaking, wobbling, jumping, bouncing, running, and cavorting) when one word would suffice.