# How to increase wiggle time in Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, 13.10

I would like to increase the duration of launcher wiggle when there is a new notification in an open program.
Thanks

Comment: possible solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121471/how-can-i-change-the-wiggle-time-of-urgent-animation-in-unity-launcher , more generally, there could be an solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity , if this does not help, try to add information on why it does not help, thx.

Comment: @mondjunge, thank you for your reply. i followed the suggestion in the first link you provided, but there is still no difference. The second link has no explanation regarding the feature i've been looking for.

Comment: I tried the first solution and found out, that not the wiggle time increased, but the duration of the wiggle animation increased. Meaning: Wiggle is shown the same time, but the wiggle animation is much slower now. :(

Comment: are you familiar with this function in other environments?

Comment: No, I am not... I am using Unity only, since Gnome 2 is deprecated.